# JavaScript Timespan Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime

I'm trying to build a timespan control.  Essentially, its a control that allows a user to enter years/months/days/hours for how long something took.

If you've ever used JIRA, I think they have a decent implementation of this.

[image: jira]

I'd be interested if anyone else has had a similar case and how you went about it via a control.  Also, how you would handle a timespan in JavaScript ( i was thinking milisecs ).

The goal is to create a control that lets users input timespan easily.  2 different date/time controls is very confusing for simply entering something like 3h.

Comment: what is goal? Create datetime from it? Question is pretty broad...might help updating with issues you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, parsing that input string to milliseconds is a good idea. So you can use that to do calculations later. e.g. you can then create a date object with `new Date(your-milliseconds)`.

You could write a directive for this like in the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7y8y5ffo/).

It uses a scope method `parseTime(time)` that uses a regular expression to create an array of the input. So you'll have a number and the key letter in the matched result.
The letter will be then used to get the timebase for the conversion to milliseconds and the value is the multiplier for the calculation.

To display the entered timespan later again I've created a filter to convert the milliseconds back to the "week, days, ..."-format.

The demo is working pretty well but I think there is one point that should be improved. If you enter a space between the number and the letter it won't work. e.g. 3 w 4 d 12h

But that's probably easy to fix. It should work by trimming the white-spaces in the parsing method.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', []).
constant('formatObj', {
    "w": 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // milliseconds
    "d": 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    "h": 60 * 60 * 1000,
    "m": 60 * 1000,
    "s": 1000,
    "ms": 1
})
    .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {})
    .directive('timeSpanInput', function () {
    return {
        template: '<input ng-model="time" ng-change="parseTime(time)" ' +
            'placeholder="enter time..."></input>(e.g. 3w 4d 12h)<p ng-show="timespan">timespan entered {{timespan | dateSpan}}</p>',
        controller: function ($scope, $filter, formatObj) {
            $scope.parseTime = function (timeStr) {
                var pattern = /(\d+)(\w{1,2})/g, // returns 1w, 1, w from 1w string
                    match,
                    timespan = 0;

                while (match = pattern.exec(timeStr)) {
                    console.log(match); // index=1 value 2=format letter w d h s
                    if (match.length == 3 && isNaN(match[2])) {
                        timespan += match[1] * formatObj[match[2]];
                    }
                }
                //console.log(timespan);
                $scope.timespan = timespan;
            };
        }
    };
})
    .filter('dateSpan', function (formatObj) {
    return function (date) {
        // convert milli seconds to weeks days hours minutes seconds string
        if (angular.isUndefined(date)) return; // date not defined yet.

        var dateObj = {},      // created date obj {w: 3, d: 4, h:12}
            dateResult = date, // used to calculated times
            factor = 0,  // math factor millis to weeks, hours, etc.
            result = ''; // formatted result string

        for (var key in formatObj) {
            factor = formatObj[key];
            dateObj[key] = Math.floor(dateResult / factor);
            dateResult -= dateObj[key] * factor;
        }

        // console.log(dateObj);
        // generate output string
        for (var key in dateObj) {
            if (dateObj[key]) {
                result += (dateObj[key] + key + ' ');
            }
        };
        //console.log('res', result);
        return result;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-contoller="mainCtrl">
    <time-span-input></time-span-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Great example! I polished some of your code to be more 'angular' . chk it out https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/f5f6372e57c3c455f85e

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code and you're right, it's more 'angular'. The `$formatters` and `$parsers` were new to me. I've updated the regex in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7y8y5ffo/5/). Now it is more robust: case insensitive & no white-space issues (3w or 3 w).

Comment: Ah, thats great! We should Github this!

Comment: Yes, that would be good. I've seen in your gist that you're importing angular into the gist. Is this the way to code with ES6? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: ES6 modules via systemjs